# ¿Por que devuelve "TypeError: string indices must be integers" este script

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

El siguiente script, me devuelve el error que menciono en el título.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import date

def get_quotes(ticker, start_day, end_day):
    yfObj = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    value_name = yfObj.info['shortName']
    df_val = yf.download(ticker, start= start_day, end = end_day, progress=False)
    df_val.rename(columns={'Adj Close': value_name }, inplace=True)   
    df_value = df_val.copy(deep=True)
    df_value.drop(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'], axis=1 , inplace=True)

    return df_val, df_value, value_name

ticker_val = 'AAPL'
start_date = "2010-01-04"
end_date = "2021-03-05"
#end_day = date.today()

# Market quotes
df_val, df_value, value_name =  get_quotes(ticker_val, start_date, end_date)
df_val
```

Me devuelve.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_20690/2061734020.py in <module>
     19 
     20 # Market quotes
---> 21 df_val, df_value, value_name =  get_quotes(ticker_val, start_date, end_date)
     22 df_val

/tmp/ipykernel_20690/2061734020.py in get_quotes(ticker, start_day, end_day)
      5 def get_quotes(ticker, start_day, end_day):
      6     yfObj = yf.Ticker(ticker)
----> 7     value_name = yfObj.info['shortName']
      8     df_val = yf.download(ticker, start= start_day, end = end_day, progress=False)
      9     df_val.rename(columns={'Adj Close': value_name }, inplace=True)

~/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yfinance/ticker.py in info(self)
    136     @property
    137     def info(self) -> dict:
--> 138         return self.get_info()
    139 
    140     @property

~/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yfinance/base.py in get_info(self, proxy)
    892     def get_info(self, proxy=None) -> dict:
    893         self._quote.proxy = proxy
--> 894         data = self._quote.info
    895         return data
    896 

~/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yfinance/scrapers/quote.py in info(self)
     25     def info(self) -> dict:
     26         if self._info is None:
---> 27             self._scrape(self.proxy)
     28             self._scrape_complementary(self.proxy)
     29 

~/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yfinance/scrapers/quote.py in _scrape(self, proxy)
     56         json_data = self._data.get_json_data_stores(proxy=proxy)
     57         try:
---> 58             quote_summary_store = json_data['QuoteSummaryStore']
     59         except KeyError:
     60             err_msg = "No summary info found, symbol may be delisted"

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

La causa no está en estas sentencias.

```
df_val = yf.download(ticker_val, start= start_date, end = end_date, progress=False)
df_val.rename(columns={'Adj Close': ticker_val }, inplace=True)   
df_value = df_val.copy(deep=True)
df_value.drop(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'], axis=1 , inplace=True)
df_value
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me mosquéa es que fasta hace unos días, el script me funcionaba sin problemas.

¿Cuál puede ser la causa?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: El error se produce cuando se intenta ejecutar el código `json_data['QuoteSummaryStore']`. Esto no lo haces tú, sino alguna parte de alguna de las librerías que usas (probablemente yfinance). Y el problema es que en ese punto el código está esperando que la variable `json_data` contenga un diccionario, pero por lo que se ve contiene una cadena. Por eso no puede acceder a un elemento usando `["nombre"]`. ¿Por qué tiene una cadena en vez de un diccionario? Pues asumo que sea debido a que el servidor no está devolviendo en ese momento un JSON válido. Tal vez ha devuelto una cadena (texto HTML)

Comment: Por tanto, yo diría que, o bien es un problema termporal del servidor, que se "arreglará solo", o bien es que el endpoint al que se intenta acceder ha dejado de responder correctamente, ha desaparecido, o está respondiendo errores debido a que hayas agotado alguna cuota máxima de peticiones al día, o algo de esto